# Hibernate mapping generic class with @MappedSuperClass ancestor

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0

I've run into a problem and I don't know, if is possible to solve it. Let me show you my code and explain the situation. I have an abstract class `User` mapped as superclass.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class User extends AbstractEntity {                     
}
```

Then I have two classes, `Person` and `Company`, extending the superclass.

```
@Entity
public class Person extends User {
}

@Entity
public class Company extends User {
}
```

Since this, everything is ok. I have two tables called by the entity names and it works june fine. But, I have some entity called `Invoice`, where I have to map `Person` or `Company` into.

```
@Entity
public class Invoice extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", updatable=false)
    private Class<? extends User> user;
}
```

The problem is that I don't know, which implementation of `User` will be mapped to this `Invoice` entity. With this solution, Hibernate gives me an error `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.xxx.user references an unknown entity: java.lang.Class` 
I understand it, but please, is there any way to implement this behaviour without an exception ? Or am I completely wrong and nothing similar can be done in ORM ?

**I cannot use `private User user` because `User` is a `@MappedSuperclass`, not an `@Entity`.**

Thanks !

Comment: Use http://sscce.org/ to get better and faster answers. There is so much unnecessary code here..

Comment: Ok, I've just edited it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well instead of using lower bound, why not just use the type `User`:

```
@Entity
public class Invoice extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", updatable=false)
    private User user;
}
```

Like this, you should still be able to put any class that extends from the `User` class as the previous declaration. However this will not work as `User` is not an `Entity`.

It should however work, if you declare `User` as entity but set inheritance strategy to `TABLE_PER_CLASS`.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class User extends AbstractEntity {                     
}
```

Comment: It cannot be done because `User` is `@MappedSuperclass`, not an `@Entity`

Comment: Yes, it's definitely what I wanted. Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept an answer, if your problem is solved, to close the question.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` should be put on the base class, not on the child class

Comment: @parsecer I don't think you're right, but I haven't worked with Hibernate in years so take it with a grain of salt. But I believe you can put the annotation on abstract class if it extends another abstract class. This [article](https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/mapping-inheritance-in-hibernate) shows the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate won't see the generic "User" at runtime (type erasure).

Use `User` instead of `Class<? extends User>`

Note that even if Hibernate *could* see the generic type, you'd still have a user `Class` not a `User`...